# DateTime conversion - server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've declared my DateOfBirth property as string and am parsing it to DateTime before passing it to the database, coz the DateOfBirth column is in DateTime format there.

in my local system, the conversion is working fine, but after hosting the application to the server, the DateTime conversion showing error like "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I've tried with

```
 <system.web>
  <globalization culture="en-gb"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
```

and

```
DateTime.Parse(DateOfBirth, new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

no use, whats this issue, can anyone help me here...

Comment: Can we see the date you are passing in that is not being converted?

Comment: DateTime.parse("04/13/1988",new CultureInfo("en-GB"))

Comment: You can also use ParseExact or TryParseExact functions.

Comment: 4/13/1988 is in MM/DD/YYYY format. Isn't the British standard DD/MM/YYYY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same prob, I changed the culture info in web.config file as:

```
<globalization culture="en-gb" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

OR

try parsing your string to date as:

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

hope it helps... :)

Comment: it showing error like "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar"......am passing the date "04/13/1988"

Comment: i tried changing ur format like "MM/dd/yyyy"...its working fine thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that according to the culture, you are passing in an invalid date. Generally, British dates are written with the day first, then the month. You're passing in 4/13/1988, which parses out to the 4th day of the 13th month. What month is 13? I don't know, and neither does the .Net Runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it, something like:

```
var sqlDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I think he's trying to go from string to Date, and you are going from Date to string.

Comment: @therealmitchconnors If he's passing it to SQL it will need to be a string in that format :)

Comment: @mattytommo: actually the type of DateOfBirth in db is DateTime, not string

Comment: Yeah that's fine, passing it what I've said in my answer is exactly the format that SQL needs it in :)

Comment: When you use myDateTime.Date, time part will be 00:00:00

Comment: sorry I tried ur method but its showing error like "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvide'".....but when I parse like "DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
" its working